# Exporting vertical 3D surface in Geosoft Oasis to ArcGIS/ Arc Scene

Tags: arcgis-desktop, 3d-analyst, arcscene, geosoft

I have point resistivity data with x,y,z coordinates and a data value (which is resistivity).

I can display it in Oasis Geosoft Montaj through gridding, as a 3D vertical surface.

How can I export this to be compatible with and view in ArcScene?

[image: resistivity profile]